# How can i identify pdf orientation whether landscape or portrait using itextsharp library in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Can any one know how can I identify pdf orientation whether landscape or portrait using itextsharp library in `C#`.

Here is my code below, It is retrieving `PDF` stream and rotating the image, but my problem is that how can we identify orientation?

```
public static string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
        {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {




            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);



            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Document doc = new Document();
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
                doc.Open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                PdfImportedPage page;
                PdfReader reader;
                reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                // loop over document pages
                for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                {

                    page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                    //Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(0);
                    AffineTransform scale = new AffineTransform(0, 1.0F, -1.0F, 0, 500, 500);
                    cb.AddTemplate(page,scale);
                }

                doc.Close();
                var rotatedFile =  ms.GetBuffer();

                ms.Flush();
                ms.Dispose();
                string filepath = @"D:\test2.pdf";
                File.Delete(filepath);
                using (FileStream Writer = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    Writer.Write(rotatedFile, 0, rotatedFile.Length);
                    string actualFilePath = "test2.pdf";
                    filepath = actualFilePath;
                }


            }
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I evaluate the rectangle size of a page to find that out. Something to keep in mind... you can have multiple orientations within the same file, so you can't decide a file is landscape based on solely the first page. A file is landscape if all the pages are landscape, otherwise it's a mixed orientation file.

```
Rectangle currentPageRectangle = pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(<PageNumberHere>);
if (currentPageRectangle.Width > currentPageRectangle.Height)
{
    //page is landscape
}
else
{
    //page is portrait
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea of scale? Like if pdf is portrait then we perform        
         'AffineTransform scale = new AffineTransform(0, 1.0F, -1.0F, 0, 500, 500);cb.AddTemplate(page,scale);'
otherwise on landscape check i dont want to give any scale so i want default scale how can i gave default scale?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about scale.